# Batch renaming files in MAC OSX

Tags: bash, macos

I have several thousand files with name like this:

```
PIN_PMN_PT_010_02_00331_0004_018edf
```

and need to rename them all something like this:

```
PIN_PMN_PT_010_02_00331_0004_018.edf
```

I have used simple mv scripts like this:

```
for f in *; do echo mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr 'edf' '.edf'`"; done
```

For some reason it creates names like this:

```
PIN_PMN_PT_010_02_00331_0004_018.ed
```

They are missing the last `f`. I am running the script using echo to dry run. Any ideas please?

Using MACBook Pro running Mohave 10.14.6 and Bash.

Comment: use bash's ***parameter expansion***!  `mv "$f" "${f%edf}.edf"`!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use shell ***Parameter Expansion***!

Simply under any [shell](/questions/tagged/shell):

For the test, `echo` to show what's will go:

```
for file in *edf ;do echo mv "$file" "${file%edf}.edf" ;done
```

Then, for doing the job:

```
for file in *edf ;do mv "$file" "${file%edf}.edf" ;done
```

(This must work same on MacOs, than under Linux.)

### ... And to prevent renaming of already correctly named files:

```
for file in *edf ;do test -f "${file##*.edf}" && mv "$file" "${file%edf}.edf" ;done
```

Syntax `${file##*.edf}` will replace any string, terminated by `.edf`, by an empty string. So `test -f ""` will fail.

... Still: I don't have any Mac for doing the test, but as this is *POSIX Standard*, this **must** work on any [shell](/questions/tagged/shell). (Let my know, please comment!)

### More infos?

Have a look at `man sh` or `man bash` and search for `Parameter Expansion`

```
man -P"less +'/Parameter Expansion'" bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, this should work

```
for f in *; do echo mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed 's/.\{3\}$//`.edf"; done
```

You are just removing the last 3 characters of a string, and adding your file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find the `rename` command invaluable for this sort of thing:

```
rename 's/edf$/.edf/' *edf
```

If you want to do a dry-run, you can do:

```
rename --dry-run 's/edf$/.edf/' *edf
```

**Sample Output**

```
'PIN_PMN_PT_010_02_00331_0004_018edf' would be renamed to 'PIN_PMN_PT_010_02_00331_0004_018.edf'
```

The benefits of using rename are:

- it can do a dry-run to test before you run for real
- it will create all necessary directories with the -p option
- it will not clobber (overwrite) files without warning
- you have the full power of Perl available to you and can make your renaming as sophisticated as you wish.

---

As helpfully suggested by F. Hauri in the comments, you may have some files that have already had the dot inserted before the extension in your directory. To protect against insertion of a second dot, you could either be more specific in the files you select for renaming and only rename those ending in a digit followed by `edf`:

```
rename 's/edf$/.edf/' *[0-9]edf
```

Or, as F.Hauri suggested:

```
rename 's/([^.])edf$/$1.edf/' *edf
```

---

Note that you can install on macOS with homebrew:

```
brew install rename
```

Comment: Main advantage of this are prevent rename of already dotted files: `rename 's/([^.)]edf$/$1.edf/' *edf`

Comment: @F.Hauri Good suggestion. I’ll edit it into my answer later. Thank you.